# How to get folder structure including items from list, without using webservices

Tags: list, content-type, feature, caml-query, folder

I have a list containing folders and items. The folders are a custom content type based on folders, with some extra columns like URL and some Yes/No Checks. One contenttype can contain n items and contenttypes.

So lets say I have this structure:

```
FolderA
   ItemA.1
   FolderA.2
      ItemA.2.1
      ItemA.2.2
   FolderA.3
FolderB
  ItemB.1
  ItemB.2
```

How can I get this structure without using the list-webservice? I know how to get all items in the list, but that returns only items, not the content types. It's also (in my opinion) no good way to do a single query against each folder because the list will get very large.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution on my own:

http://blog.krichie.com/2007/01/30/traversing-sharepoint-list-folder-hierarchies/

**Edit (5 years later):**

From the site mentioned above

> It’s actually very easy, but I would vote it’s a horrible way to have
>   to go about it.
>
> Enter SPQuery:

```
private static void TraverseListFolder(SPFolder folder)
{
    // Get the collection of items from this folder
    SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
    qry.Folder = folder;

    SPWeb web = null;
    try {
        web = folder.ParentWeb;
        SPListItemCollection ic = web.Lists[folder.ParentListId].GetItems(qry);

      foreach (SPListItem subitem in ic){
            Console.WriteLine(“List item: “ + subitem.Name);
         Console.WriteLine(“List item type: “ + subitem.ContentType.Name);

            if (subitem.Folder != null)
                TraverseListFolder(subitem.Folder);
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  } finally {
        // Cleanup that nasty web reference.
      if (web != null)
            web.Dispose();    
  }
}
```

> Ok so cool, we now have a way to get ONLY the items in a folder within
>   a list at any level without introducing any items that are not in
>   scope.
>
> So, we’ll just use this method, and to traverse the list, but hey,
>   where do you start? Well, fortunately SPList exposes a RootFolder
>   property that gives you a SPFolder object to start with J
>
> So we can write our List traversal Kick off method as such:

```
private static void TraverseList(SPList list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(“Traversing list: “ + list.Title);
    Console.WriteLine(“Base Type: “ + list.BaseType.ToString());
    TraverseListFolder(list.RootFolder);
}
```

> Simply pass in a reference to a list, and away we go. Very compact,
>   and it works regardless if the list being passed in is a Document
>   Library or any kind of list.

Comment: +1 Good job finding your solution. You should summarize what you learnt from the link here (in case the link goes down, and to have a more useful post here).

Comment: @Mzn You're right - I implemented the important part from the post :-)

Comment: I just noticed that it's 5 years old! Good job expanding your answer; it looks so much better now!